# JavaScript setInterval for outline color flicker not working after first change of color

Tags: javascript, css, setinterval, getelementbyid, var

I'm trying to change the outline color of an H1 element every 2 seconds. So I used this JavaScript code... But it only changes from yellow to orange once and stays at Orange the entire time. What can I do to make it Flicker between the two colors? Please respond in JS terms and not JQuery Library

Here is my JavaScript Code, I'm new to JS :

```
var myVar = setInterval(function(){ colorFlicker() }, 2000);

function colorFlicker(){
    var y = document.getElementById("mainH1");
    y.style.outlineColor = y.style.outlineColor == "#ff944d" ? "#d9ff66": "#ff944d";
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't check for colors in javascript, the returned color depends on the browser, and is often in the format `rgb(200,33,33)` or `rgba(244,22,244,1)` or even hex in older browsers, use a flag instead

```js
var myVar = setInterval(colorFlicker, 500);

var flag = true;

function colorFlicker() {
    var y = document.getElementById("mainH1");
    y.style.outlineColor = flag ? "#d9ff66" : "#ff944d";
    flag = !flag;
}
```

```css
#mainH1 {outline: 2px solid #ff944d;}
```

```html
<h1 id="mainH1">TEST</h1>
```

Comment: can you explain in words what the flag is doing after you create variable "y" in the colorFlicker() function?

Comment: Can anybody show me how to do what adeneo did with an if, else statement using the flag? That was really interesting but since I'm new, I'm a little lost on the control flow.

Comment: It's the same as the code you had, the flag starts out `true` and doing `flag = !flag` reverses it, so `true` becomes `false` and the next time `false` becomes `true` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use `rgb()` for the default color then adapt your condition :

```js
var myVar = setInterval(colorFlicker, 1000);

function colorFlicker() {
  var y = document.getElementById("mainH1");

  y.style.outlineColor = y.style.outlineColor == "rgb(255, 148, 77)"?"#d9ff66":"rgb(255, 148, 77)";
}
```

```css
h1 {
  outline-style: dotted;
  outline-color: rgb(255, 148, 77);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id='mainH1'>mainH1</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Style changes should be handled with CSS. You can then use JavaScript to safely toggle a class that would attach the CSS style to your elements:

```
/* css */
#mainH1 { outline: /* some color */ }
#mainH1.alternateColor { outline: /* some other color */ }

// JS
var y = document.getElementById("mainH1");
function colorFlicker(){
  y.classList.toggle('alternateColor');
}
```